# SEVERE: Could not dispatch event: Eventbus com.google.common.eventbus.SubscriberExceptionContext

Tags: java, spring, guava

For EventBus, I merged the code inside my java Spring app and have full control of it but the result didn't change.

When I run The EventBus in spring sts (javaw), there is no issue but when I run in the server with java -jar project.jar  it gives the same SEVERE: Could not dispatch event: error

The below didn't work for me..

```
package edu.uams.event;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.google.common.eventbus.AsyncEventBus;
import com.google.common.eventbus.EventHandler;
import com.google.common.eventbus.SubscriberExceptionHandler;


import edu.uams.domain.TirEvent;
import edu.uams.pacs.IncomingFileMonitor;

public class AysncTraumaEventBus extends AsyncEventBus {

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AysncTraumaEventBus.class);
    private String name = null;

    public AysncTraumaEventBus(Executor executor,
            SubscriberExceptionHandler subscriberExceptionHandler) {
        super(executor, subscriberExceptionHandler);    

        logger.info("AysncTraumaEventBus created.");
    }

    public AysncTraumaEventBus(String name, Executor executor) {
        super(name,executor);
        this.name=name;
        logger.info("AysncTraumaEventBus created. Name:"+this.name);
    }

    @Override
    public void register(Object object) {
        super.register(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void unregister(Object object) {
        super.unregister(object);
    }   

    @Override
    public void dispatch(Object event, EventHandler wrapper) {
        try {
          logger.info("Let's dispatch Aysnchroneous Trauma Event:"+ ((TirEvent) event).getResultMessage());
          wrapper.handleEvent(event);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
          // My logger
          logger.error("Could not dispatch event: " + event + " to handler " + wrapper+"  e:"+e.getMessage());
          logger.info("Lets try to disptach again!");
          super.post(new ExceptionEvent(event, e));         
        }
      }


    public static final class ExceptionEvent {
        public final Object event;
        public final InvocationTargetException exception;

        public ExceptionEvent(final Object event, final InvocationTargetException exception) {
            this.event = event;
            this.exception = exception;
        }
    }
```

}

Somehow the EventHandler can't invoke the target event..

wrapper.handleEvent(event);

When you look the wrapper (EventHandler):

```
public void handleEvent(Object event) throws InvocationTargetException {
    checkNotNull(event);
    try {
      method.invoke(target, new Object[] { event });
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      throw new Error("Method rejected target/argument: " + event, e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
      throw new Error("Method became inaccessible: " + event, e);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
      if (e.getCause() instanceof Error) {
        throw (Error) e.getCause();
      }
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

You see that method.invoke(target, new Object[] { event });  throws the InvocationTargetException from the Method.class

```
public Object invoke(Object obj, Object... args)
        throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException,
           InvocationTargetException
    {
        if (!override) {
            if (!Reflection.quickCheckMemberAccess(clazz, modifiers)) {
                Class<?> caller = Reflection.getCallerClass(1);

                checkAccess(caller, clazz, obj, modifiers);
            }
        }
        MethodAccessor ma = methodAccessor;             // read volatile
        if (ma == null) {
            ma = acquireMethodAccessor();
        }
        return ma.invoke(obj, args);
    }
```

Somehow it can't invoke.. But the most interesting part is that the same jar file along with EventBus can run fine in STS Run (javaw) but when I run java from commandline as java -jar project.jar it can't dispatch the event..

Comment: I was having the same problem as you. It turned out that my problem was an exception was happening in my `@Subscriber` method. Try to wrap a `try catch` around your `@Subscriber` method that is receiving the event. If you received an exception try to solve it, then it should be working fine. Good luck and let me know if it solved your problem as well.

Comment: You were right, the @Subscribe method needs have try catch, otherwise it is more likely to fail for any small exception

Comment: Well, not always I guess. It's up to you, when you believe an exception *can* occur there. But if you want to play on the 100% safe side, then you can always use a `try catch` block. But be careful as you may be catching `Exception`s that mean "nothing" (I mean, don't catch the general `Exception`, be specific.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
@Subscribe
@AllowConcurrentEvents
    public void receivedDicomFile(TirEvent event){                  

        try {



            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            } catch(Exception e){
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }



    }
```

It always needs an try catch.. Thanks @dwnz for your help